# Cut Java String at a number of character

Tags: java, string

I would like to cut a Java String when this String length is > 50, and add "..." at the end of the string.

***Example :***

I have the following Java String :

```
String str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz";
```

I would like to cut the String at length = 8 :

Result must be:

```
String strOut = "abcdefgh..."
```

Comment: Usually it makes more sense to cut so that the length won't be more than N with an ellipsis.  The difference being that in you example 9, 10 or 11 character strings would be cut even though they would be shorter, or the same length.

Answer (score 41):

Use substring and concatenate:

```
if(str.length() > 50)
    strOut = str.substring(0,7) + "...";
```

Answer (score 35):

`StringUtils.abbreviate("abcdefg", 6);`

This will give you the following result: `abc...`

Where 6 is the needed length, and "abcdefg" is the string that needs to be abbrevieted.

Comment: if you had written 'and "abcfudhrenflöerhbfhlredbl" is the...' my mind will much faster get what you mean. :D :D Thanks anyway :)

Comment: This answer should be accepted, since it's the most accurate.

Answer (score 15):

Use substring

```
String strOut = "abcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz"
String result = strOut.substring(0, 8) + "...";// count start in 0 and 8 is excluded
System.out.pritnln(result);
```

Note:  substring(int first, int second) takes two parameters.  The first is inclusive and the second is exclusive.

Comment: This will throw an exception if `strOut` is shorter than 8 characters.

Answer (score 12):

Jakarta Commons [StringUtils.abbreviate()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#abbreviate%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). If, for some reason you don't want to use a 3rd-party library, at least copy the [source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/lang/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java?view=markup).

One big benefit of this over the other answers to date is that it won't throw if you pass in a null.

Answer (score 7):

You can use safe substring:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.substring(str, 0, LENGTH);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [String#substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

```
if(str != null && str.length() > 8) {
    return str.substring(0, 8) + "...";
} else {
    return str;
}
```

You could however make a function where you pass the maximum number of characters that can be displayed. The ellipsis would then cut in only if the width specified isn't enough for the string.

```
public String getShortString(String input, int width) {
  if(str != null && str.length() > width) {
      return str.substring(0, width - 3) + "...";
  } else {
      return str;
  }
}

// abcdefgh...
System.out.println(getShortString("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 11));

// abcdefghijk
System.out.println(getShortString("abcdefghijk", 11)); // no need to trim
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this may be:

```
String str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz";
if (str.length() > 8)
    str = str.substring(0, 8) + "...";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String strOut = str.substring(0, 8) + "...";
```