# Preferences in Java

Tags: java, exception, jar, preferences

I would store my object inside the `.jar` using `java preferences`.

I convert my object into a String and i store it.

I use this code to save it:

```
Preferences.userNodeForPackage(Centrale.class).put("myValue", myString);
```

I use this code to read it:

```
String myString = "";
myString = prefs.get("myValue", myString);
```

I find an error when i save a big string. The error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value too long
java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences.put(AbstractPreferences.java:245)
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need to break the String into length of Preference.MAX_VALUE_LENGTH.  I would suggest that you create myValue.1, myValue.2, etc... That are related to myValue. When loaded you just string the values together.

Here is some code:

```
    String value = "....";
    int size = value.length();
    if (size > Preference.MAX_VALUE_LENGTH) {
      cnt = 1;
      for(int idx = 0 ; idx < size ; cnt++) {
         if ((size - idx) > Preference.MAX_VALUE_LENGTH) {
           pref.put(key + "." + cnt, value.substring(idx,idx+Preference.MAX_VALUE_LENGTH);
           idx += Preference.MAX_VALUE_LENGTH;
         } else {
           pref.put(key + "." + cnt, value.substring(idx);
           idx = size;
         }
      }
   } else {
      pref.put(key, value);
   }
```

There is also a limit on the key size which is Preference.MAX_KEY_LENGTH.

One more point to make is that you can then use the Preference keys method to recreate your object.

Comment: This has helped me with storing a lengthy JSON string inside a preference value.

Comment: how to retrieve this value and gathering as a same old string ?

Answer (score 1):

You could cut your String in parts as the exception is saying that your String is too long

An example in how to split a string at certain character count can be found at [Cut Java String at a number of character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685977/cut-java-string-at-a-number-of-character)

```
if(str.length() > 50) //if the string length > 50
strOut = str.substring(0,50) //return substring from first character to 8 character
strOut2 = str.substring(51, str.length) //second part
```